# How to use String.match() in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this code here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo">Display the result here.</p> 
<input type = "text" value = "ood" id = "txt1"/>
<script>


var myString = "How much wood could a wood chuck chuck";
var myWord = document.getElementById("txt1").value;   // ood
var myPattern = /.myWord/;        // I want this to be /.ood/
var myResult = myString.match(myPattern);

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myResult;

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Now what I want to do here is that I want the value of the `txt1` which is `ood` to be matched in `myString`.

But putting the variable `myWord` into the `myPattern` like this: `/.myWord/` won't work. Need help please. Many thanks

**UPDATE:**

I did everything as what it is in the answers but it returns `wood,wood` instead of `wood` only, I just wanted to get only 1 match. Just like using for example `/.ood/` - this only returns 1 match. Please help

And also, how can I get the word `wood` by having only `od` in my input text. I just wanted this for searching..

Comment: Use `RegExp` constructor syntax as `var myPattern = new RegExp('\.' + myWord, 'gi');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a string as a regular expression using the [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) Object:

```
var myPattern = new RegExp('.'+myWord,'g');
```

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/zz3mpyvo/)

Doing a single match in your case, is simply changed the second parameter in `RegExp` from `g` to `m` (which means to make one match per line for multi lines, but in this case a strings is simply all one line). For finding the word `"wood"` from `"ood"`,`"od"`,`"d"`, or other cases. You can do this:

```
var myPattern = new RegExp("\\b\\w+"+myWord+"\\b",'m');
```

*Note I have a solution in the comments below, but this one is better.*

The items `\\b ... \\b` mean [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). Basically ensuring that it matches a single word. Then the `\\w` means any valid *"word character"*. So overall the regexp means (using `myWord = "od"`):

> |word boundary| + (1 or more word characters) + "od" + |word boundary|

This will ensure that it matches any words in the string than end with the characters `"od"`. Or in a more general case you can do:

```
var myPattern = new RegExp("\\b\\w*"+myWord+"\\w*\\b",'m');
```

Comment: Thanks it worked and actually found the match but what i just wanted is to get only 1 match. Thanks.

Comment: @wwwDELL In that case you can use `RegExp('.'+myWord,'m');` to get a single match in this case. The `m` means to do a match for each line.

Comment: Thanks! it really worked. I also updated my question. when the value of the input text is `od` it supposed to find `wood` but it could'nt match any word from that of myString :(

Comment: @wwwDELL Is it returning the value `"odd"`? If so this is because `.` means only a single character. So in your string the matched item would be `odd` other than `wood` since `wo` is two characters.

Comment: Yes it is. and I don't know why?

Comment: @wwwDELL Edited my comment above with why that happens. So for example you can fix that by doing `new RegExp('.{1,2}'+myWord,'g')`., meaning you can have 1 to 2 characters before `od`.

Comment: It also worked but how about when it reaches to 3 or more characters. Is there any way to not manually do it like using `{1,2}` or `{1,2,3}`? But rather use a dynamic one?

Comment: @wwwDELL Yes there is, but it has some overhead. You can split the string up by it's words. Then use `new RegExp(".+"+myWord+"$",'g');` to mean: *1 or more characters + ends with "od"* on each word. [Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/zz3mpyvo/1/). It's possible there is a better way to do that.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot for this help. You're awesome. It really worked. But unfortunately i don't understand how it worked but anyways i'll just try to comprehend this onel. Thanks again.

Comment: @wwwDELL No problem, I've actually found a better solution to what I mentioned, I've added it to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Create a Regexp object like

```
new RegExp('.ood','g');
```

like in

```
var searchstring='ood' // this is the one you get in a variable ...

var myString = "How much wood could a wood chuck chuck";
var myPattern=new RegExp('.'+searchstring,'gi');
var myResult = myString.match(myPattern);
```

Comment: would you site some example please?

Comment: The string `ood` should be dynamic from the textbox value, see my comment  above

Comment: You also need to escape `.` by preceding \, in regex

Comment: Well, yes, then do that too ;-) BuI I understood that OP actually wanted to look for an "arbitrary character" not the actual dot.

Comment: Thanks it worked and actually found the match but what i just wanted is to get only 1 match. Thanks.